# Appium+Android+webdriverio, how to click on element of a list

Tags: android, node.js, appium, webdriver-io

I started using Appium to run UI test on Android apps (and possibly iOS once I get it to work on Android)

I'm trying to run a test using `nodeJS` and `webdriverio`.

The thing is, I can't seem to click on an element of a list (the list is dynamically created so elements all have the same id)

Here is the node code. When I run it, appium correctly starts an emulator and opens my app:

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8.0",
    deviceName: "Android Emulator",
    app: "/path/to/application.apk",
    appWaitActivity: "com.package.SomeActivity",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2",
    avd: "Nexus_5X_API_26"
  }
};

const client = wdio.remote(opts);


client
  .init()
  .elements('id:theIdOfTheList') // This retrieves a list of 4 elements
  .element()[3] // This gives a NoSuchElementError
  .end();
```

What should I use in place of `.element()[3]` to make this work (or is there a completely different way I should do it?)

I see in appium that the 4 elements of the list are retrieved:

> Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"1c21baa1-60ec-4e5f-b51f-f738698660ad","status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"53d31f1f-af25-4621-85cd-b2f881a5c770"},{"ELEMENT":"4c3909ab-6f65-426a-b831-9a7d5e069ba8"},{"ELEMENT":"e0fd1f12-0193-48ea-a168-4d45f63d27b3"},{"ELEMENT":"87b7abda-3738-4411-a544-572243cd7502"}]}

Comment: When I try your example I get `client.init is not a function`. Do you have an example of successfull test? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Node.js, but from the looks of it you're not storing that array of elements anywhere and your subsequent element() call is merely looking for another unrelated element. Since you've provided it no search parameters, it finds nothing.

Pardon my ignorance of your language, but something like the following should get you what you want:

```
.elements('id:theIdOfTheList')[3]
```

Comment: Hello. I expected that it would work that way and tried it already. But the usage of the webdriverio is a bit more complex. All these function translate to HTTP requests. Accessing an element with [] doesn't work.

Comment: I'll stop commenting on something I don't know about then.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. ( I use sync mode for webdriverio). This may work in
asyc mode.

```
client
.init()
.elements('id:theIdOfTheList', function(err, resp) {
 resp.value.forEach(function(elem) {
  // log elem
       })
  })
.end();
```

Comment: Hello. I have seen a few examples like this one. But it doesn't seem to call the anonymous function. Is there a way I could store values in variables? Having to bind all the functions together between .init and .end is painful